# Typescript cannot find modules that are already installed

Tags: typescript, electron

I am trying to build a client that runs on Electron with Typescript, however, I am getting errors from the `request.ts` files.

[image: code snippet from resourceRequest.ts]

The same thing happens on main.ts that I got from the [Electron Typescript quickstart](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start-typescript) when it tries to import `electron`.

`tsconfig.json` is configured as follows:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES2015",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "types": [ "node" ],
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

I made sure that `baseUrl` points to the directory `node-modules` is in so I'm sure the compiler can find `node-modules`.

And just to assure you that `axios` and `electron` are installed, here is `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "electron-quick-start-typescript",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A minimal Electron application written with Typescript",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "lint": "eslint -c .eslintrc --ext .ts ./src",
    "start": "npm run build && electron --no-sandbox ./dist/main.js"
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start-typescript",
  "keywords": [
    "Electron",
    "quick",
    "start",
    "tutorial",
    "demo",
    "typescript"
  ],
  "author": "GitHub",
  "license": "CC0-1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/electron": "^1.6.10",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.42",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.33.0",
    "electron": "^18.2.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0"
  }
}
```

When I specify module as `commonjs` I can get it running but I also get errors because `tsc` compiles import statements as `require` which isn't supported by browsers.

I tried using `tspath` but I couldn't run in it as I'm using Windows 11. I also tried giving relative paths but then I ended up with errors saying that "there were no declarations found" for those files. I would really appreciate any tips on how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can help you is by letting you see my tsconfig.json that I use in every project. Try to copy and paste it inside yours.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "src/types"
    ],
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: This helped get rid off the errors with the imports but now I've got errors in the try-catch blocks saying that ```Object is of type 'unknown' console.log('error message: ', error.message);```

Comment: According to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60151181/object-is-of-type-unknown-typescript-generics
You have two options:
1. `} catch(e) {
    if (e instanceof Error) {
        console.log(e.message)
    }
}`
2. Add this under "strict" in tsconfig.json `"useUnknownInCatchVariables": false`

Comment: Thanks! But now there are also messages stating ```'resourceCategory.ts' cannot be compiled under '--isolatedModules' because it is considered a global script file. Add an import, export, or an empty 'export {}' statement to make it a module.```. Removing this option from the config file results in ```main.js import { app, browserWindow } from "electron";        cannot use import statement outside a module```

Comment: I can't help you with that, I need to see some code to understand. Just mark the answer as correct (it currently answered your questions), then open another ticket with the problem you are currently facing (with details, screens of code) and I can help you easily

Comment: Will do. Thank you for the fixes so far :)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem with the `dotenv` module on TypeScript.
[Screenshot with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMNbL.png)
The solution for TypeScript to recognize the module is to stablish the `moduleResolution` as `"moduleResolution": "node"` on the `ts.config` file.
[ts.config gile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEvL7.png)
Once you stablish this prop, the error should dissapear.

---

I use a minimal config for TypeScript as my project just started development, but I'm sure my `ts.config` file will be helpful:

```
{ //ts.config
 "compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es2016",
   "module": "ES6",
   "rootDir": "./src",
   "moduleResolution": "node",
   "outDir": "./dist",
   "esModuleInterop": true,
   "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
   "skipLibCheck": true
 }
}
```